# MenuItem with dynamic value is not working in Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Select, in Material UI for React, I always get undefined when i select from selector.
It always happen when we use `MenuItem` value *dynamic*. But if i use static value instead of using dynamic, it works well. But I have to use in dynamic way with `.map` operator.

Please provide the solution which works well in dynamic value.

Like this  ->  `<MenuItem value={SOME-DYNAMIC-VALUE} />`

```
this.state.selectedTagetIdentity = '';

onTargetIdentityChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ selectedTagetIdentity: event.target.value }); // its undefined always 
}

const splitedIdenties = { 
 'abc1' :[{ id: 12, age: '2' },{ id: 13, age: '3' }], 
 'abc2': [{ id: 14, age: '22' },{ id: 15, age: '25' }] 
};
```

```
<Select value={selectedTagetIdentity} onChange={onTargetIdentityChange}>
  {Object.keys(splitedIdenties).map((identityTypeKey, identityTypeIndex) => 
    <div key={identityTypeIndex}>
      <ListSubheader>{identityTypeKey}</ListSubheader>
      {splitedIdenties[identityTypeKey].map(identity => 
        <MenuItem key={identity.id} value={identity.id}>{identity.age}</MenuItem>
        )}
    </div>
  )}
</Select>
```

**See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jfumi) it's not working**

Comment: Have you tried it without the div wrapping the ListSubHeader and MenuItems?

Comment: please provide live demo

Comment: @xadm i have added link above, please check.  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jfumi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you are wrapping `MenuItem` with `div`. `MenuItem` elements must be direct descendants of material-ui [`Select`](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/):

> ⚠️The MenuItem elements must be direct descendants when native is
>   false.

To fix that, remove the wrapping div:

```
<Select value={personName} onChange={onTargetIdentityChange}>
    {Object.keys(splitedIdenties).map((identityTypeKey, identityTypeIndex) =>{
    let children = [];

    children.push(<ListSubheader>{identityTypeKey}</ListSubheader>); 
      splitedIdenties[identityTypeKey].forEach(identity => {
        children.push(<MenuItem key={identity.id} value={identity.id}>{identity.age}</MenuItem>)
      })

      return children;
    }
  )}
</Select>
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: You can use `<ListSubheader/>` (or any other) components instead of `<MenuItem disabled>` - as you wrote - only requirement, all `<ManuItem/>` must not be wrapped, have to be direct child of `<Select/>`

Comment: @xadm Thanks! you are right. There is actually nothing wrong with Listsubheader. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Ido this works but is console 2 errors are coming. Please can you tell how we can overcome with those.

Comment: @hardy You didn't mention when the errors are thrown, I guess when you click on the SubListheader? If it is the case, a way to overcome this is to use <MenuItem disabled> instead of ListSubheader. You can see example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-qgf87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)